# Nested for loops with if statement gives too many answers

Tags: bash

I would like to compare one textfile, line by line, with another textfile, to find out how many times the same text appears in text file 2. The problem is that I am getting too many loops.
How do I solve this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read text file
echo "Enter file name"
read fname

# Read text file
echo "Enter file name"
read fcheck

# rm out2.txt
c1=0

for i in $(cat $fname);

do
    for j in $(cat $fcheck);
    do

        if [[ $i == $j ]]
        then
            let c1=c1+1;
        fi

    done

    echo $c1 # >> out2.txt
    c1=0;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `for` loops is that they read the files *word-by-word*. Instead, do something like this:

```
while read line_a
do
    while read line_b
    do
        if [ "$line_a" = "$line_b" ]
        then
            let c1=c1+1;
        fi
    done < "$fcheck"

    echo $c1
    c1=0;
done < "$fname"
```

Make it a habit to enclose variables in quotation marks, like `"$var"`, to avoid problems with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

[`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) is really what you need:

```
common_lines=$(comm -12 <(sort "$fname") <(sort "$fcheck"))
printf "%d common lines:\n" $(wc -l <<< "$common_lines")
echo "$common_lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
 fname=file1.txt
 fcheck=file2.txt

 cat "$fname" | while read line 
 do
     echo -e "$(fgrep -c "$line" "$fcheck")\t$line"
 done
```